# Nodejs - Can't se Gradle in Environment?

Tags: android, gradle

I am a beginner and I want to run Cordova using nodejs and have gone through all of the instructions for installing and setting up the environment variables but it reports that it can't find the Gradle wrapper. Here is the error:

> Blockquote
> C:\cordova\hello>Cordova build android
> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\tehud\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
> ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
> Using Android SDK: C:\Users\tehud\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
> Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
> or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
> in your path, or install Android Studio

I have checked the environment variable and they are correct!
I even uninstalled Android Studio and reinstalled it, but I get the same error.
Is there a way that I can check Android Studio to see if it is installed there.
As I said I am a beginner so I have no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the original answer I found on the internet showed the environment as gradle, but it should have been GRADLE_HOME. Now builds with errors. Will re-post with error.